# InvalidActorNameException - actor name {name} is not unique

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, akka

So I'm getting started using Akka actors inside of my Play 2.0 app. I noticed quickly that repeated calls to sending messages to the same actor, specified via:

```
val myActor = Akka.system.actorOf(Props[MyActor], name = "myactor")
```

Resulted in `InvalidActorNameException`.

I then started reading up on the creation of Actors in this [doc](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.2/scala/actors.html#Creating_Actors_with_default_constructor)

The doc seemed to recommend creating a "master" Actor class with all of the individual actors specified in there. The `receive` of this actor class would, in turn, match on the message and delegate the message to the appropriate Actor.

So I tried this and now have something like:

```
class MasterActor extends Actor{
  import context._
  val emailActor = actorOf(Props[EmailActor], name = "emailActor")
  protected def receive = {
    case reminder : BirthdayReminder => emailActor ! reminder
  }

}
```

Problem is that I'm in the same situation I was before. I don't know how to avoid the `InvalidActorNameException` when I try something like:

```
    val myActor = Akka.system.actorOf(Props[MasterActor], name = "MasterActor")
    myActor ! BirthdayReminder(someBirthday)
```

So what's the right way to organize my Actors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want only one MasterActor, why are you creating multiple ones? You should just look up the one you have already created:

```
val actorRef = context.actorFor("MasterActor")
actorRef ! BirthdayReminder(someBirthday)
```

Comment: Thanks Kim. Appreciate your help. I know this probably a stupid question, but where would I initially create the MasterActor? In other words, somehwere I need to create it with system.actorOf, no?

Comment: Yes, you can do that whereever you want as long as it only happens once.

Comment: Thanks Kim. One last question: How can I grab the context outside of a class that extends Actor? That val is protected, but I need the context elsewhere...

Comment: Why do you need the context? To look up an actor, you can also use ActorSystem.actorFor

Comment: Bit confused. In the case of my Play app I should initialize the MasterActor when my app starts (    Akka.system.actorOf(Props[MasterActor], name = "MasterActor")) and then later call val masterActor = Akka.system.actorFor("MasterActor")?

Comment: @LuxuryMode, the actorref is thread safe and can be passed around freely, but the context is _not_ thread safe and should not be passed around between actors (or other entities) - this is the reason for it being so well hidden. The context of an actor should only be used from inside that actor, and only in Actor callbacks.

Comment: Hmm, just doesn't seem to be working for me. My Actor just doesn't seem to be receiving the messages. I'm doing something wrong here...